Analog story - US provides food machines to other nations, with hidden feature
This is a near present day story for the time of publication - late 1990s/early 2000s, I think. At Christmas time, the US is sending devices (nanotech, I think) that can create food from non-organic raw materials (and perhaps build shelters). The protagonist learns that the food is adulterated with mind-control factors. When the protagonist asks what will happen when Congress finds out, he's told that the administration has sent every Congressmember a gift basket for the holidays.

Peace on Earth, Good Will to Men by Rick Shelley.
Nanotech device using local materials:

And there are sources people can help provide . Plastics, wood ash, organic waste . This system can liberate hydrogen and turn it into water from all of those. Our planes are going to start bringing in bales of discarded plastics. once the food packets get going around the area. We're going to start a self-sustaining water cycle, Reggie, really we are. "


"The molecular assemblers that grab oxygen from the air to make the water will also help minimize evaporation - almost like a sheet of plastic wrap across the surface. We can't eliminate evaporation completely, but we don't want to. Seepage will be held to a minimum by the sludge that will line each pond. The seepage and evaporation that do occur will help make the ground fertile again."

The Catch:

"In six months, half the people in the world will have our custom-designed molecular computers in their systems, interacting strongly with their own brains, informing, improving, guiding."

Congress:

"Our preparations were very thorough, Matt. Every representative and senator received a box of Christmas candy from the White House. We catered the dinner the president hosted for Congress just before the holiday adjournment - and the meals for the last two days in the restaurants that most of our congressmen use around Capitol Hill."


Here you go: https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/luminist/SF/AN/AN_1989_12_15.pdf

Thank you for that

Thanks.  Now fixed.
